# what need to be done when we change the manage account password from the Active directory

Tags: 2013, security, administration, configuration, application-pool

We have changed the passwords for the SP manage accounts inside our active directory. So I login to the SP server, then i changed the application pool identify passwords accordingly. Then I went to “Central administration >> Security >> General Security >> Configure managed accounts ”, I saw that the “last password change” column was changed accordingly to match today date as follow:-

[image]

So I though that I do not need to manually change the manage accounts passwords inside central administration, but when I try viewing the search service's content source  I got the following error:-

> Sorry, something went wrong  Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {0FF1CE15-0005-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due
>   to the following error: 8007042d The service did not start due to a
>   logon failure. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007042D).

So i realize that SP did not get the new password, so I went back to the managed accounts inside CA, I edit it , then I chose to “change password now >> Use existing password” and I entered the new password there as follow:-

[image]

so now I can access the search service’s content source.

So can anyone advice on this , I mean do I need to manually changed the SP managed account password , whenever we change their password inside active directory? and why the SP did not change the password accordingly when we changed it on active directory,,, I mean the “last password change” column inside the CA page was changed to today date , but seems the password inside SP did not change ,, or not sure what happened ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the password the Active Directory then it will not updated in the SharePoint even it gets the new change date from the AD.

I can tell you what we adopt after couple of outages.

- Change the Password in AD.
- Update the Password in the SharePoint
- Now test it, if it is populated on all servers.(we perform IIS reset on all server in the Farms.

You can change from SharePoint and force it to change in AD as well but in our case we always end up to lock our account.

Comment: so to change the password from SP , i will go to “Central administration >> Security >> General Security >> Configure managed accounts ”, then edit the manage account ,then I chose to “change password now >> Use existing password” , then enter the updated password.. is this corect ?

Comment: That's correct, once u change it AD.

Comment: and well changing the manage account password from the CA ,, take effect on the IIS application pools identity ? i do not think so ?

Comment: in either case, whenever you update the Managed Account Password either first ad then SP or directly from SP to AD...SharePoint Push this change to everywhere this account is being used.....but will not update non sp stuff i.e schedule task etc